# listing the files in a directory and delete them in C/C++

Tags: c, linux

In a "C" code I would like to list all the files in a directory and delete the oldest one. How do I do that?

Can I use popen for that or we have any other solutions??

Thanks,

Comment: Plain C doesn't have any notion of directories, so you'll need to specify which OS you want to do this for.

Comment: @caf: actually plain C (which seems to imply the programming language itself) doesn't even have a concept of files or anything else for that matter. C is comprised of about 32 keywords, a few operators and that is it. All these notions of files, directories, etc. are all defined in libraries. So if you didn't mean the language definition itself, then the question is are directories defined in standard C libraries? and the answer is YES .. In particular dirent.h interface to OS concept of directories is both an X.Open and POSIX.1 standard.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: There is a C standard library that is specified as part of the programming language itself: a conforming hosted implementation of C must provide `fopen()`, for example.  The `dirent.h` interface, on the other hand, is *not* a part of standard C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the tag, I assume that you want to do this in a POSIX compliant system. In this case a code snippet for listing files in a folder would look like this:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

DIR* dp;
struct dirent* ep;
char* path = "/home/mydir";

dp = opendir(path);
if (dp != NULL)
{
  printf("Dir content:\n");
  while(ep = readdir(dp))
  {
    printf("%s\n", ep->d_name);
  }
}
closedir(dp);
```

To check file creation or modification time, use `stat` (man 2 stat).  For removing file, just use function `remove(const char* path)`

Comment: I am not entirely sure that it is safe to remove a file in an open-ed directory (because the scanned directory is updated while it is scanned). My suggestion would be to do that in two passes: the first is scanning, and finding the files to remove, the second is removing them.

Comment: This is very good remark. However in this case you have to finish scan before removing anyway, since the OP wants to remove the oldest file (you have to check all files to find the oldest).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux (and indeed, any POSIX system), you read a directory by calling `opendir()` / `readdir()` / `closedir()`.  You can then call `stat()` on each directory entry to determine if it's a file, and what its access / modification / status-change times are.

If your definition of "oldest" depends on the *creation* time of the file, then you're on shaky ground - traditionally UNIX didn't record the creation time.  On Linux, some recent filesystems do provide it through the extended attribute `file.crtime` (which you access using `getxattr()` from `sys/xattr.h`), but you'll have to handle the common case where that attribute doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the directory using [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) and [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) 
or, if you want to traverse (recursively) a file hierarchy [fts](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fts) or [nftw](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw). Don't forget to ignore the entries for the current directory `"."` and the parent `".."` one. You probably want to use the [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) syscall too.

Comment: You can't use `readdir()` without `opendir()` -- one isn't perferred to the other.